# Tensorflow combined non max suppression for candidate regions of an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I want to run combined non max suppression in a set of
windows for an image.
I am using tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression from tensorflow as follow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf 



boxesX=np.array(([200,100,150,100],[220,120,150,100],[190,110,150,100],[210,112,150,100])).astype('float32')
scoresX=np.array(([0.2,0.7,0.1],[0.1,0.8,0.1],[0.3,0.6,0.1],[0.05,0.9,0.05]))
boxes1=tf.reshape(boxesX,(1,4,1,4))
boxes2=tf.dtypes.cast(boxes1, tf.float32)
scores1=tf.reshape(scoresX,(1,4,3))
scores2=tf.dtypes.cast(scores1, tf.float32)

boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
boxes=boxes2,
scores=scores2,
max_output_size_per_class=10,
max_total_size=10,
iou_threshold=0.5,
score_threshold=0.2)
```

But the output 'boxes' is just an array of zeros and ones:

```
array([[[1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 2):

The boxes are being clipped between `[0,1]`. All you need to do is add the argument `clip_boxes=False`:

```
boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
boxes=boxes2,
scores=scores2,
max_output_size_per_class=10,
max_total_size=10,
iou_threshold=0.5,
score_threshold=0.2,
clip_boxes=False)
```